# Vector Analysis in Version 8

Tags: vector

Silly question.

Why does

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Grad[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, y}]
```

give the error

> Coordinates::invalid: "{x,y} is not a valid coordinate system specification"

in Mathematica version 8?

I'm a bit of a novice, but I would have thought that should evaluate to something sensible.

Thanks,
David

Comment: `Grad[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, y}]` works as you would expect in Ver 10 (and you don't need the `Needs`). Don't know about Ver 8.

Comment: I think this is from the version 8 documentation. Needs["VectorAnalysis`"];
Grad[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, Cartesian[x, y, z]]

Comment: Thanks Bill.

I've upgraded to version 10 and I don't see the same message now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(*
"8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
*)

Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
```

From the help file of VectorAnalysis you find the following useful commands

```
CoordinateSystem

(*
Out[17]= Cartesian
*)

Coordinates[] (* These are not x, y, z but ... *)

(*
Out[20]= {Xx, Yy, Zz}
*)
```

Now you have

```
Grad[Sin[Xx^2 + Yy^2]]

(*
Out[19]= {2 Xx Cos[Xx^2 + Yy^2], 2 Yy Cos[Xx^2 + Yy^2], 0}
*)
```